# Idiomatic encapsulation in Clojure: How can data be bundled with linked behavior?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, encapsulation

I'm trying to figure out whether Clojure is something that can fully replace the paradigms that I'm used to in other languages.  One thing that I don't understand is how to idiomatically achieve encapsulation in Clojure (by encapsulation I'm referring to the bundling of data with the methods (or other functions) operating on that data).

Here is a use case from OOP:

```
var apple = {
    type: "macintosh",
    color: "red",
    cost: 5
    markup: 1.5
    getInfo: function () {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    }
    getPrice: function(){
        return this.cost * this.markup;
    }
}
```

OR similarly:

```
var person = {
    birthdate: '8/30/1980',
    firstname: 'leeroy',
    middleinitial: 'b',
    lastname: 'jenkins',
    getAge: function () {
        return -(new Date()
 - new Date(this.birthdate));
    }
    getFullFormattedName: function () {
        return capitalize(this.firstname+' '+this.middleinitial+' '+this.lastname;
    }
}
```

It's often convenient to bundle the behavior with the data in this way, but what is the idiomatic way that Clojure allows this problem to be solved?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In idiomatic clojure your functions do not *belong to* data, they *operate on* these data. In place of structures [maps](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Maps%20%28IPersistentMap%29) or [records](http://clojure.org/datatypes) are used, and you define functions which take these structures as parameters. For example, your apple example could look like this:

```
; Define a record type with given fields
; `defrecord` macro defines a type and also two constructor functions,
; `->apple` and `map->apple`. The first one take a number of arguments
; corresponding to the fields, and the second one takes a map with
; field names as keys. See below for examples.
(defrecord apple [type color cost markup])

; Define several functions working on apples
; Note that these functions do not have any kind of reference to the datatype,
; they exploit map interface of the record object, accessing it like a map,
; so you can supply a real map instead of record instance, and it will work
(defn get-info [a] (str (:color a) " " (:type a) " apple"))
(defn get-price [a] (* (:cost a) (:markup a)))

; Example computation
; Bind `a` to the record created with constructor function,
; then call the functions defined above on this record and print the results
(let [a (->apple "macintosh" "red" 5 1.5)
      a-info (get-info a)
      a-price (get-price a)]
  (println a-info a-price))
; Will print the following:
; red macintosh apple 7.5

; You can also create an instance from the map
; This code is equivalent to the one above
(let [a (map->apple {:type "macintosh" :color "red" :cost 5 :markup 1.5})
      a-info (get-info a)
      a-price (get-price a)]
  (println a-info a-price))

; You can also provide plain map instead of record
(let [a {:type "macintosh" :color "red" :cost 5 :markup 1.5}
      a-info (get-info a)
      a-price (get-price a)]
  (println a-info a-price))
```

Usually you use records when you want static object with known fields which is available from Java code (`defrecord` generates proper class; it also has numerous other features, described at the link above), and maps are used in all other cases - keyword arguments, intermediate structures, dynamic objects (e.g. the ones returned from sql query) etc.

So in clojure you can think of *namespace* as a unit of encapsulation, not *data structure*. You can create a namespace, define your data structure in it, write all the functionality you want with plain functions and mark internal functions as private (e.g. define them using `defn-` form, not `defn`). Then all non-private functions will represent an interface of your namespace.

If you also need polymorphism, you can look into [multimethods](http://clojure.org/multimethods) and [protocols](http://clojure.org/Protocols). They provide means for ad-hoc and subtyping kinds of polymorphism, that is, overriding function behavior - the similar thing you could do with Java inheritance and method overloading. Multimethods are more dynamic and powerful (you can dispatch on the result of *any* function of the arguments), but protocols are more performant and straightforward (they are very similar to Java interfaces except for inheritance and extendibility).

**Update:** a reply to your comment for the other answer:

> I am trying to determine what the approach that replaces methods of
>   OOP

It is helpful to understand what exactly 'methods of OOP' are.

Any method in conventional object-oriented language like Java or especially C++ essentially is a *plain function* which takes an *implicit argument* called `this`. Because of this implicit argument we think that methods "belong" to some class, and these methods can operate on the object they are "called on".

However, nothing prevents you from writing friendly global function (in C++) or public static method (in Java), which takes an object as its first argument and performs all the things which are possible to do from a method. No one does this because of *polymorphism*, which is usually achived with the notion of methods, but we are not considering it right now.

Since Clojure does not have any notion of 'private' state (except for Java interop functionality, but that is completely different thing), functions do not need to be connected in any way with the data they operate on. You just work with the data supplied as an argument to the function, and that's all. And polymorphic functionality in Clojure is done in different way (multimethods and protocols, see the links above) than in Java, though there are some similarities. But that's the matter for another question and answer.

Comment: Thanks for this response.  I'll have to consider this and see if it's the organizational solution that I was looking for.  I take it that the (let [a lines allows the passing of the functions to act similar to a method?  Or perhaps it's more similar to a global function bound directly to the specific data.   I'm not actually able to get the code to work in an online repl: http://tryclj.com/ but that may be a version mismatch or something?

Comment: Yes, tryclj seems to have old version of Clojure without records support. However, records implement map interface, so you could safely use simple map here instead of record. `(let ` is start of lexically scoped variables definition - the content inside square brackets is variable bindings. In the example I bind variable 'a' to the result of `(->apple` function call, `a-info` to the result of `(get-info` call and so on, and then these variables can be used inside the body of `(let` block. This is not related to encapsulation, this is general language construct.

Comment: Sorry, I just found out that I've messed up with records. In `defrecord` definition field names should be symbols rather than keywords. I've updated the code example.

Answer (score 4):

Create a hashmap of closures that have **this** in their lexical scope.  It's not that different from your original Javascript code.

```
(defn apple-object [this]
  {:get-info  #(str (this :color) " " (this :type) " apple")
   :get-price #(* (this :cost) (this :markup))})

(defn person-object [this]
  {:get-age
   #(- (-> (java.util.Date.) (.getTime))
       (-> (this :birthdate) (.getTime)))

   :get-full-formatted-name
   #(clojure.string/join
     " "
     (map clojure.string/capitalize
          [(this :firstname) (this :middleinitial) (this :lastname)]))})

;;;; usage ;;;;

(def apple (apple-object
            {:type    "macintosh"
             :color   "red"
             :cost    5
             :markup  1.5}))

(apple :type)

((apple :get-info))

((apple :get-price))


(def person (person-object
             {:birthdate     (java.util.Date. 80 7 30)
              :firstname     "leeroy"
              :middleinitial "b"
              :lastname      "jenkins"}))

(person :birth-date)

((person :get-age))

((person :get-full-formatted-name))
```

Answer (score -8):

Don't do it.  You're trying to write OOP in FP.  Which is as bad an idea as writing Chinese in English.

Comment: I'm not trying to do that, but I am trying to determine what the approach that replaces methods of OOP is.